# If a step-up transformer increases voltage, then how current can be decreased ? is really the current in output is smaller?

Tags: transformer

**If a step-up transformer increases voltage, then how current can be decreased ?**

[image: there is something very-much paradoxical !!!!]

If a step-up transformer increases voltage, then how current can be decreased ?

(I'm trying to ask that, in case-of battery, if I take a battery of lower voltage (say 10 Volt), and another battery of higher-voltage (say 50 volt), and use them in  2 separate circuits (each with same path-resistance , say 2 Ohm ) ; then , in the circuit that got stronger-battery (50 V), will give much more current.

Now, instead of batteries; we're taking 2 AC sources:  an AC source of 10 V , and another similar AC-source of 10 V magnified to 50 V through a step-up transformer.

Since a step-up transformer increases voltage and decreases current; then , that 50 V AC source should give LESSER CURRENT than the 10 V (according to conservation of energy).

But common sense is telling, if there is a potential difference of 50V, then we SHOULD get a MUCH GREATER CURRENT THROUGH OUTPUT(Load) circuit, than the 10V source;  since we know from Ohm'law  (and even non-ohmic conductors with any positive resistance), that, if we apply greater voltage, we'll obtain greater current.

Then, among these 2 thoughts (assumptions) , which one is correct?  and why?

& if the first assumption is correct ( "the 50 V transformer gives 1/5 times lesser flow than the 10V  original source", then why we're telling it 50V  at all; and not saying 10/5 or 2 volt? )

And if it is really works just like a true 50V source and increase current, then how it obey at all the law of Conservation of energy?

See also: [How do Step Up Transformer work? on this website (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/how-do-step-up-transformers-work)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/how-do-step-up-transformers-work)

and

[On that page, an answer , explaining how each loop work as a battery. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/how-do-step-up-transformers-work/11006#11006](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/how-do-step-up-transformers-work/11006#11006)

However I'm not a physics or math person. So please explain that way.

Comment: Pin = Pout. If you change to a step-up transformer and keep the same load, then the input current will go up as well.

Comment: so you are are saying that a step up transformer should create energy from nothing?  you have solved our energy crisis!  as Tom above say power in = power out.  p = vi so vout*iout = vin*iin, iout = (vin/vout)*iin.  Actually you probably lose a little in heat as part of the conversion, nothing is free.

Comment: Those resistors you have on the primary side will make it so the voltage across the primary winding is **NOT** 10V!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A transformer essentially converts between voltage and current using a magnetic field. Because it is a conversion, then if the process is 100% efficient, then the output power and input power must be equal:

$$P_{in} = P_{out}$$

If they are not equal, then either you are losing energy in the transformer (inefficiencies), or gaining energy (perpetual motion anyone?!). The former can happen, the latter can't.

So based on this, what can we say about the voltage and current? Well, we know that:

$$P = I V$$

So:
$$I_{in}V_{in} = I_{out}V_{out}$$

Lets say that you have a step up transformer with 10 turns on the primary and 50 turns on the secondary. This means you have a turns ratio of:

$$n = \frac{50}{10} = 5$$

So that means that the voltage will be increased by a factor of 5 (\$V_{out} = 5\times V_{in}\$). So what happens to the current?

$$I_{in}V_{in} = 5V_{in}\times(I_{out})$$

In order for both sides of that to stay equal (can't get energy from nothing!), then the current must be divided by 5. Basically you can say that:

$$I_{out} = \frac{1}{n}I_{in}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space V_{out} = nV_{in}$$

---

So what happens if you have a fixed load and change the number of turns? Lets do an example. We shall say that the input voltage is \$10\mathrm{V}\$, the transformer initially steps up by a factor of \$n=1\$, and then later by a factor of \$n=5\$. In both cases the output load is a \$2\Omega\$ resistor.

In the first case, your calculations are correct.

$$V_{out} = n\times V_{in} = 10\mathrm{V}$$
$$I_{out} = \frac{V_{out}}{R_L} = \frac{10}{2} = 5\mathrm{A}$$
$$I_{in} = n\times I_{out} = 5\mathrm{A}$$

Now lets go for \$n=5\$.

$$V_{out} = n\times V_{in} = 5\times 10 = 50\mathrm{V}$$
$$I_{out} = \frac{V_{out}}{R_L} = \frac{50}{2} = 25\mathrm{A}$$

Great, these match what you are saying. But this is where everything changes. We do the last step of the calculation:

$$I_{in} = n\times I_{out} = 5\times 25 = 125\mathrm{A}$$

Ahh, there we go. Notice that the input current goes up, quite considerably. This makes the scales balance so to speak - power in goes up in order to cope with the large power requirements of the load.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Oh. that means , on the output-circuit of transformer , when the current is allowed, it also induces increase-of current in input-circuit of the transformer?  i.e. in my diagram, I've considered  the input circuit with 2  Ohm, 10 V, 5 Amp irrespective of output circuit switched on or off. If the OUTPUT CIRCUIT TURNED ON, then the flow on input circuit will AFFECTED, INCREASED, & become 125 A? Have I got it correctly?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused correct. The load on the output will directly affect the load on the input. In fact you can say that the output is "referred" to the input: \$R_{in} = \frac{R_{out}}{n^2}\$.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused also, in my first comment I wasn't talking to you. Somebody downvoted the answer and I was asking them why if they happened to look back.

Comment: (@ Tom Carpenter)  Oh I feel quite relieved  since it goes quite with logic. The step-up transformer outputing that extra energy by enhance sucking the current on primary coil. Contd...

Comment: ...Contd .     However, still it giving rise to another Paradoxical question. According to LENZ's law,  the induced electric current always take place in such a direction that always repell the moving magnet / hinder alteration of magnetic field. If so, then Why in case of transformer, the secondary coil enhancing flow in primary coil, instead of hindering? in-fact more current-output in secondary coil (more turn-nos) enhancing flow in primary coil rather than hindering?

Comment: What will happen in case of step-Down transformer? will it reduce the current on primary coil (just in reverse with step-up transformer?)?

Comment: The equations are just as valid for a step down. \$n\$ is now going to be <1. E.g. 10:1 will be \$n=N_s/N_p=1/10 = 0.1\$.

Comment: @Tom: Hi Tom. I was wondering if you could kindly clear up this confusion that I have. In the case of \$ n = 5 \$, you have shown that \$ I_{\text{in}} = 125 \text{A} \$, so the effective resistance of the primary circuit is \$ R_{\text{in}} = \dfrac{10}{125} \Omega = 0.08 \Omega \$. It thus appears that the Ohmic resistance (\$ 2 \Omega \$) of the wiring in the primary circuit plays absolutely no role in your calculation. However, what would happen if I were to insert an Ohmic resistor of, say, \$ 10 \Omega \$ into the primary circuit?

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore the calculations were about the transformer - so Vin is considered the voltage across the transformer primary. You can work out the voltage applied to the whole circuit (including the input resistor) by continuing to work backwards in this example. In a practical case you work forwards knowing what the input voltage to the whole circuit is, not the transformer, and you can put the referred resistance in series with the input resistance to work out current through and voltage across the transformer primary.

Comment: @Tom: Ah! Are you therefore saying that in the equation \$ I_{\text{in}} V_{\text{in}} = I_{\text{out}} V_{\text{out}} \$, the quantity \$ V_{\text{in}} \$ refers to the voltage drop across only the transformer primary (i.e., the portion of the primary circuit coiled around the core) and not to the voltage drop across any other part of the primary circuit?

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore correct.

Comment: @MiniMax Define \$I_2\$.

Comment: Can't get right formatting :). Will ask without it. Two questions. 1) How in this case high voltage transmission have possible? Because it uses transformers to decreasing current in lines, but from your logic, current increased to 125 A on input wires (lines), instead 5 A at the beginning. 2) What prevent infinite loop (runaway) in the transformer, like, first step: I in = 5 A -> I out = 25 A, second step: I in = 125 A -> I out = 625 A, third step... etc?

Comment: High voltage transmission uses step up transformers to decrease the current in the transmission lines, and step down at the other end. My "logic" (aka physics) says nothing to the contrary. The current didn't "increase to 125A instead of 5A" because of the transformer, it increased because the effective load increased. If you stick a 2R resistor across a 50V supply, it will draw more current than if you stick it across a 10V supply. There isn't some magic infinite loop runaway thingy going on here.

Comment: The circuit on the left and the circuit on the right are not directly comparable because the load is different. In the second circuit, having stepped up the voltage, to keep the same input power the load would be a 10R resistor. In the case of HV transmission, the load remains unchanged, yes, but you don't get 415kV delivered to your house - there is a step down transformer at the other end.

Comment: I should also point out that in the OPs diagram, the label "10V 5A" on the second circuit is wrong. With a 2R resistor across the output of that transformer, the current at the input would need to be 125A. It doesn't keep increasing each time you do the calculation. In fact you can do the calculation again now: \$I_{out} = \frac{1}{n}I_{in} = \frac{1}{5}\times 125=25\mathrm{A}\$. Bingo, we hit a steady state - the output current matches.

Comment: (@MiniMax, also on EE to do MathJax in comments you use \$ around it rather than just $)

Answer (score 3):

A transformer can not create power so a step-up in a sense both increases the current and reduces it.

If we have 10V ac supply and connect a 10 ohm resistor across it we will have 1 amp flowing in the resistor. If we now disconnect and replace it with a 2:1 step-up transformer connecting the same 10 ohm resistor across the secondary then the resistor will have 20 volts across it so will have 2 amps flowing in the resistor.  Thus the current in the resistor has increased as you have pointed out.

However, this is not the sense in which we mean a step-up transformer reduces the current. If we consider the power in the resistor in our second case we have 2 amps and 20 volts making a total power of 40 watts. We therefore need at least 40 watts to be flowing into the primary. This means the current into the primary has to be at least 4 amps because we only have a 10 volt supply. In practice we will have slightly more than this because no transformer is 100% efficient, there are conduction losses in the windings and some power is needed to magnetise the core but the current may only be slightly higher than this as efficiencies in excess of 90% are easily achievable.

When we say a step-up transformer reduces the current we mean we have less current in the secondary than we do in the primary.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the transformer is ideal(i.e no power losses). A transformer conserves power, that is, if you're consuming 12 W at the secondary side, the same amount of power is drawn from the power source of the primary side(ex mains).

For your example: The no-load output voltage is 50 V. If you connect a load of, say 100 ohm, a 0.5 A (RMS) current would flow in the secondary side, while 2.5 A (RMS) would be drawn from the 10V AC source.

What you must understand is that current drawn from the AC source depends on the current at the secondary side.

Answer (score 1):

To give an insight why a transformer works this way, understand that the strength of a magnetic field (formally, the magneto-motive force or MMF) is measured in [Ampere-Turns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere-turn).

So you apply an AC voltage (\$ V \$) to the transformer’s primary (of \$ N \$ turns), and that drives a specific current (\$ I_{0} \$) through the primary inductance, and that current creates a magnetic field of \$ N I \$ ampere-turns.

So far, the secondary is open-circuit and we take no power out of it, which is why I’ve labelled this current as \$ I_{0} \$. It generates the magnetic field, so it’s called the “magnetisation current”.

Now, the current \$ I_{0} \$ can be calculated from the primary inductance \$ L \$, the driving voltage and the AC frequency by standard AC formulae. You’ll find this if you look, but the important point is, this is all wasted power, so you want \$ L \$ (and therefore \$ N \$, since \$ L = N^{2} A_{L} \$) to be large enough to keep wasted power down to a few percent. (Here, \$ A_{L} \$ is the ‘specific inductance’, which is a property of the transformer core).

---

Now, what happens if we draw a current \$ I_{2} \$ from the secondary, with \$ N_{2} \$ turns? This current also creates a magnetic field, of \$ - N_{2} I_{2} \$ ampere-turns, i.e., in the opposite sense to the field created by the primary. (because \$ I_{2} \$ is drawn from the secondary instead of fed into it.)

This decrease in the magnetic field reduces the ability of the primary to block primary current flowing (i.e., its impedance), so primary current increases until the MMF is back to the original \$ N I_{0} \$ ampere-turns. (This is for a perfect transformer. A real transformer doesn’t work quite as well as you have to consider the ‘leakage inductance’, but ignore that for now.)

So the primary current is now \$ N I_{0} + N I_{1} \$, where \$ N I_{1} \$ generates MMF to exactly cancel the secondary current’s MMF, so
$$
N I_{1} = N_{2} I_{2} \qquad \text{or} \qquad
I_{1} = \left( \frac{N_{2}}{N} \right) I_{2}.
$$
In other words, for a step-up transformer where \$ N_{2} > N \$, the primary current must increase to generate the same MMF.

So the secondary current is determined by the secondary voltage and the load, and the primary current is determined by the secondary current (plus \$ I_{0} \$ the ‘magnetisation current’).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more complete analysis, based on my discussions with Tom Carpenter above (please see our comments under his post).

---

Let us establish some terminology first:

1. \$ V \$ is the voltage of the AC source.
2. \$ R_{1} \$ is the resistance of the wiring of the primary circuit.
3. \$ R_{2} \$ is the resistance of the wiring of the secondary circuit.
4. \$ n_{1} \$ is the number of turns in the primary coil.
5. \$ n_{2} \$ is the number of turns in the secondary coil.
6. \$ V_{1} \$ is the back e.m.f. induced in the primary coil.
7. \$ V_{2} \$ is the e.m.f. induced in the secondary coil.
8. \$ V_{3} \$ is the voltage drop across the wiring of the primary circuit due to resistance.
9. \$ I_{1} \$ is the current in the primary circuit.
10. \$ I_{2} \$ is the current in the secondary circuit.

The first five quantities are assumed to be already known, while the last five quantities are to be expressed in terms of the first five.

---

Now, form the following five equations:

1. \$ V = V_{1} + V_{3} \$, by Kirchoff’s Second Law.
2. \$ V_{3} = I_{1} R_{1} \$, by Ohm’s Law.
3. \$ V_{2} = I_{2} R_{2} \$, by Ohm’s Law.
4. \$ I_{1} V_{1} = I_{2} V_{2} \$, by the Law of Conservation of Energy.
5. \$ \dfrac{V_{1}}{n_{1}} = \dfrac{V_{2}}{n_{2}} \$, by Faraday’s Law of Induction.

Plugging Equation (2) into Equation (1) yields
$$
V = V_{1} + I_{1} R_{1}.
$$
From Equation (5), we have \$ V_{1} = \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} V_{2} \$, so
$$
V = \frac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} V_{2} + I_{1} R_{1}.
$$
Using Equation (3), we find that
$$
V = \frac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} I_{2} R_{2} + I_{1} R_{1}.
$$
From Equations (4) and (5), we have \$ I_{2} = \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} I_{1} \$, so
$$
  V
= \left( \frac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} \right)^{2} I_{1} R_{2} + I_{1} R_{1}
= I_{1} \left[ R_{1} + \left( \frac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} \right)^{2} R_{2} \right].
$$
Solving for \$ I_{1} \$, we therefore obtain
$$
I_{1} = \frac{V}{R_{1} + \left( \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} \right)^{2} R_{2}}.
$$
Consequently,
\begin{align}
    I_{2}
& = \frac{\left( \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} \right) V}
         {R_{1} + \left( \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} \right)^{2} R_{2}}, \\
    V_{3}
& = \frac{V R_{1}}{R_{1} + \left( \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} \right)^{2} R_{2}}, \\
    V_{1}
& = \frac{\left( \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} \right)^{2} V R_{2}}
         {R_{1} + \left( \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} \right)^{2} R_{2}}, \\
    V_{2}
& = \frac{\left( \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} \right) V R_{2}}
         {R_{1} + \left( \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}} \right)^{2} R_{2}}.
\end{align}

---

> **Conclusion:** Ohm’s Law is in harmony with the Law of Conservation of Energy.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused: Hi. I was wondering if you’ve managed to understand my solution to your problem.

Comment: Can you answer it without using the energy conservation argument? You are proving it while assuming it in the first place. Why I am saying this cause I have more believe in Ohm's law. I still didn't get that is it open-circuit voltage or what?

Answer (score 1):

No one has answered the question in a real sense of physics, everybody answered that it's a law of conservation of energy or in terms of formula.

So I'll try to  address your curiosity and let you know that how does the coil, magnetic fields or flux know that nature has a law of conservation of energy? And I'll explain what exactly happens inside the core at on load situation.

When the primary is turned on, the current flows through the coil, it generates magnetic flux, that magnetic flux goes through the core and reaches secondary coil, secondary coil induces voltage and when load is connected to the secondary coil, the current flows through the secondary coil as a result the secondary coil creates its own magnetic field that stops the flow of current in secondary coil momentarily, and also the direction of magnetic flux that secondary coil generates is opposite to the direction of flux that's coming from the primary core.

And when this flux from secondary coil reaches the primary, it generates the current in the primary in the opposite direction, which means it lowers the impedance of primary coil, as a result primary coil draws more current from the mains and which is proportional to the load connected with secondary, because the magnetic flux that flips the direction of magnetic domains inside primary core is proportional to the current the load connected to secondary is drawing.

This is what actually happens inside a transformer under on load situation.